# Need Assistance, Swift 2.0 SKSpriteNode

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

Im quite new to swift programming language, recently I started following a Youtube Tutorial to create a space shooter game. One thing I was curious about however (not mentioned in tutorial) is how do I add a limit to the number of bullets.

```
import SpriteKit

//Declaring Player
let player = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "playerShip")

class GameScene: SKScene {

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

        //Declaring Background
        let background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "background")

        //Setting Properties For Background
        background.size = self.size
        background.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width/2, y: self.size.height/2)
        background.zPosition = 0
        self.addChild(background)


        //Setting Properties For Player (Already Declared)
        player.setScale(1.3)
        player.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width/2, y: self.size.height * 0.20)
        player.zPosition = 2
        self.addChild(player)

    }

    func fireBullet(){

        //Setting Properties & Declaring Bullet
        let bullet = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bullet")
        bullet.setScale(1)

        bullet.position = player.position
        bullet.zPosition = 1
        self.addChild(bullet)

        //Moving and Deleting Bullet
        let moveBullet = SKAction.moveToY(self.size.height + bullet.size.height, duration: 1)
        let deleteBullet = SKAction.removeFromParent()
        let bulletSequence = SKAction.sequence([moveBullet,deleteBullet])
        bullet.runAction(bulletSequence)


    }

    //This function will run when screen is touched
    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

        fireBullet()

    }

}
```

Comment: Is this a limit to the total number of bullets the player has or the number that can be in use at once? If it's the former, then appz's answer is good. If the latter, then what happens when the player reacher the limit and tries to fire another bullet? Does the oldest one disappear or can they not fire until an existing bullet has gone off screen?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to limit the total number of bullets the player can shot, then you can create a property of `GameScene` representing the number of remaining bullets

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
    private var remainingBullets = 10
    ...
```

Next, when `fireBullet()` is invoked you need to check if there are remaining bullets available. If so then the `fireBullet()` execution can continue otherwise you `return`.

Last thing you need to decrease `remainingBullets`.

```
func fireBullet(){
    guard remainingBullets > 0 else {
        print("No more bullets")
        return
        }
    /// .... Do shooting stuff in here ...
   //... 
    remainingBullets -= 1
 }
```